# Wordpress > Custom post type with Custom taxonomy > terms not linking to custom archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I am a new with wordpress, but have about 6 months experience so far so I am not a complete noob!

I have run into a problem and I just can't solve it. Any help or insights would be very welcome to get me going.

- I have created a Custom post type for 'news' - All good
- I have created a Custom Taxonomy for the news items - All good
- I have created a 'News centre' page which displays the news along with links for the terms that are attached to the news item - All good
- The term links go to the default archive.php - Not good.

I want the term links to go to a page that pulls in all the news items tagged with that term.

Here is my CPT And taxonomy function:

```
<?php
/**
* Register CPT News
*/

add_action( 'init', 'cpt_news' );
function cpt_news() {

   $labels = array(
       'name' => _x( 'News', 'post type general name' ),
       'singular_name' => _x( 'News', 'post type singular name' ),
       'menu_name' => _x( '+ News', 'admin menu' ),
       'name_admin_bar' => _x( 'News', 'add new on admin bar' ),
       'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'News' ),
       'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New News' ),
       'new_item' => __( 'New News' ),
       'edit_item' => __( 'Edit News' ),
       'view_item' => __( 'View News' ),
       'all_items' => __( 'All News' ),
       'search_items' => __( 'Search News' ),
       'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent News:' ),
       'not_found' => __( 'No News found.' ),
       'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No News found in Trash.' ),
       'featured_image'     => 'Add Featured Image',
       'set_featured_image' => 'Select an image'

  );

  $args = array(
      'description' => __( 'News' ),
      'labels' => $labels,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions',
                          //'author', 'excerpt', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields',
                        ),
   // comments was removed to disable comments.
      'hierarchical' => false,
      'public' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'show_in_menu' => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
      'menu_position' => 2,
      'can_export' => true,
      'exclude_from_search' => false,
      'capability_type' => 'news', //page
      'has_archive'     => true,
      'map_meta_cap'    => true,
 );

  register_post_type( 'news_item', $args );

}


add_action( 'init', 'cpt_news_taxonomy' );
function cpt_news_taxonomy() {

   register_taxonomy( 'news_type', 'news_item',
     array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name' => _x( 'News Topic', 'taxonomy general name', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Topic', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Topic', 'text_domain' ),
     ),
       'exclude_from_search' => false,
       'has_archive' => true,
       'hierarchical' => true,
       'show_ui' => true,
       'show_tagcloud' => true,
   )
);

}
?>
```

When I click on a news item tagged with 'Volunteering' it goes to this url: /news_type/volunteering/, which is displayed using the archive.php, even though I have created archive-news_item-volunteering.php

I am sure I am missing something really obvious!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Wordpress Codex page on [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#Custom_Taxonomies_display), you create a template file with the name of `taxonomy-news_type.php`. WordPress will use that to display the archive for that taxonomy. You can also use `taxonomy-news_type-volunteering.php` to create the template for the specific term 'volunteering' in your taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dan, that nailed it! I was thrown off by the fact it defaulted to archive.php and went down the wrong route. All working now, thanks! Have a great day!
Jason